# Maven: Jar in Referenced Libraries despite not showing in effective POM

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

Before importing my Maven project, I build it using the following: mvn clean install

I then create the necessary Eclipse files as follows: mvn -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:eclipse

I notice that my Referenced Libraries in Eclipse contains this jar: validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

However, when I view the effective POM in Eclipse no such jar appears. Therefore, I am wondering how this jar gets added to my Eclipse classpath?

I require this jar for @Valid annotation I am using and I need Maven to be aware of it. If I build my classpath files using Maven then how come Maven is not aware of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Dependency hierarchy-tab in your pom (in Eclipse), maybe the jar is a dependency of some other jar you use.

In this case, the reference was in the project's Java Build Path, and was *probably* added when the project was created because of the **-Dwtpversion=2.0** -parameter.

Comment: It does not appear in the Dependency Hierarchy tab when I search for it

Comment: Yes it is in my .classpath file if that is what you are referring to. I just ran an eclipse:clean there and then eclipse:eclipse but it still appears in the .classpath file

Comment: Java Build Path is the place where you define referenced libraries (among other things) in Eclipse project, with Maven you don't usually need to touch it yourself... Go to project properties by right-clicking the project root, select Properties, then Java Build Path -> Libraries and see if the jar is referenced there, and remove if you don't need it. Probably "something" (the terminal mvn-command?) added it there when the project was created (if it is there).

Comment: Yes, it is there. I'd still like to understand why it was added though. How reliable are these command line commands?

Comment: It was probably (yes, I'm guessing) caused by the "-Dwtpversion=2.0" -parameter, I'm not familiar with the Web Tools Project, but maybe the default configuration for such projects adds certain libraries automatically.

Comment: No problem. I've edited the answer according to the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Maven also adds to your class path the sub-dependencies of your main dependencies (which are those specifically declared by you in the pom.xml). Do a

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

To see what other dependencies are pulled in with a specific pom-declared dependency.

Also, if you only wanna see the subdependencies of a certain dependency, called x.y.z you can do:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=x.y.z
```

(where x.y is the groupId and z is the artefactId)

Comment: Ran the above command and it does not appear in the dependency tree

Answer (score 0):

One of your project dependencies probably has a dependency for this jar file. Check the graphical dependency graph or just search for that, find out your project dependency that is dependent on this and exclude this dependency, if possible, by using maven's 'exclude' tags.

You can use maven dependency exclusions, as below:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Source: [Maven - Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

Comment: See my comments below, it does not appear in the dependency tree. Where then is Eclipse picking up this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. And after some research I realized that transitive dependencies of your parent pom may not show up in Effective POM, but would be present in Reference libraries.

The whole confusion raised because when I ran the following command

`mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=X` (where X is the group-id of the jar I was looking for)

It did no mention of parent pom, instead it referred to dependency in parent pom which brings X to the table. (Which make sense because we inherit from parent pom).